# Doing Integration Testing on Simulink Models

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, integration-testing, simulink

[image]

Say, I've *[UNITs 1,2,3,4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5NvA.jpg)* ( either as Model reference or Subsystem) for which I've units tests ready using matlab.unittest.TestCase framework.

What could be the easiest way to write integration test fro entire system ?

I need some way to set *Global_Inputx* ( x = 1,2,3 ) and verify *Global_Outy* ( y =1,2 ) in easiest possible way (may be utilizing the Unit tests) ?

<sub>I can use **Matlab 14a**</sub>

<sup>PS: I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18767825/1870232) but it didn't help</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question of integration testing in Simulink is a complex one that may involve formal methods like code and coverage analysis of the dynamic system under test, automatic test generation e.t.c. If you haven't already, you may want to check out "Verification, Validation and Test" section of the MathWorks product line up: http://www.mathworks.com/products/?s_tid=gn_ps.

However to answer your specific question of how you would set the global input and verify global output in your test:

Depending on where your global input data that feeds the inport blocks resides (MATLAB base workspace, model workspace, e.t.c), do you think you could set the external input of the model to that data. For example:

> > set_param(, 'ExternalInput', )

This could be defined in your test class setup, test method setup or in the test depending on when the data is available and where defining it is appropriate. The data could also be passed in directly to the sim() command. Parameterized testing (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-basic-parameterized-test.html) is an option to consider if you want to test the system with different sets of inputs. The external input value becomes the parameter in this context.

If you have your model set up for output logging, then once the simulation is done, you would get the logged outputs, which you could then compare against a baseline.

Does that help? or am I way off the base here. If you can add more details, I can try again.

Comment: Thank you, this does help. I too was thinking along the same line. I do have a function by which I can set any external input. The only problem I'm facing is how can I utilize the unit tests, where intermediate I/Os are available. I don't want my team to re-write the entire Tests again for integration testing to verify external outputs. I was thinking if we can somehow get the expected outputs using existing unit tests by _crawling_ the unit tests with known inputs, etc. +1 btw.